# Is it possible to use abitrary-length parameters in an ILE COBOL procedure?

Tags: parameters, ibm-midrange, procedure, cobol

What I want to do is define an (AS400) ILE COBOL procedure that takes a PIC X(n) parameter, processes the string, and returns a result code to the calling program. My concerns are:

1) whatever length I select for the maximum string size, it's likely that some program will need to call it with a larger string, and

2) trailing spaces might be meaningful in terms of the result.

So, the procedure needs to be able to accept a parameter of an arbitrary length, and determine at run time what the actual length of the string is.

In reading the IBM docs, I'm inclined to believe that this can't be done. Am I right, or is there actually a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considering using ILE C or ILE RPG?  The whole point to ILE is that you can have modules written in different languages linked into a single *PGM or *SRVPGM. Thus allowing you to use the best tool for the job; instead of using a hammer to drive a screw.

Comment: If I were permitted to use C, I would.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any problem using arbitrary length arguments (other than learning how to do it). Just as with every language, you need to either define a variable-length field or receive the actual length in a second argument. The PIC will need to declare the maximum length allowed.

A variable-length argument will be like this:

```
01   VL-FIELD.  
   05   i      PIC   S9(4)   COMP-4.  
   05   data   PIC   X(n).
```

The *i* variable reports the length and PIC(n) will be coded as the maximum. You can't safely access any bytes beyond what *i* says.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to know the length of the field in your CALLed program. So I hope that you know it in your CALLing program. So if you know the length there, you will be fine.

There are generally two ways to then proceed:

1. Prefix the data with the length (common definition for a VARCHAR in COBOL)
2. Pass the length as a separate parameter

The second can be more convenient if you don't want to toss your data around just to prefix it (if it isn't already).

Type of field for the length? Binary will be good. Which binary? From your description it sounds like "native binary" would suit best, rather than a binary field with a decimal limit to the PICture size. That is perhaps COMP-4, but I haven't checked for your COBOL.

How to do the definition for field?

```
01  THE-DATA.
    05  THE-LENGTH                      COMP-4 PIC S9(4).
    05  THE-STRING.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 32767
            DEPENDING ON THE-LENGTH.
            15  FILLER                         PIC X.
```

Or

```
01  THE-LENGTH                          COMP-4 PIC S9(4).
01  THE-DATA.
    05  THE-STRING.
        10  FILLER OCCURS 0 TO 32767
            DEPENDING ON THE-LENGTH.
            15  FILLER                         PIC X.
```

In your program you just then use THE-STRING, in a MOVE or DISPLAY or whatever. Except CALL, which conveys nothing to the CALLed program except the address of the start of the data, :-)

You don't *need* a definition like that in the CALLing program, unless you want it. It is a convenient definition for the CALLed program, though there are other ways to do it, including that refuge of the scoundrel, reference-modification :-)

If you are able to compile with NOSTDTRUNC you will be able to use the above values, otherwise you'll need to define larger binary fields like PIC S9(6) at least.

Comment: Note that `COMP-5` is not a valid usage in the AS/400 line, but the ODO clause can be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks @user2338816. Do you have a binary which allows access to all the bits? Ours is COMP-5, our COMP-4 is identical to COMP and BINARY (they do decimal truncation) so looks exciting but does nothing. Lots of variation in COBOL on this. I'll change it to COMP-4 and let me know if that is wrong, please.

Comment: DB2 on i and varying-length fields in general will specify the varying prefix as COMP-4 which is equivalent to BINARY. COMP-4 can cover 2-, 4- and 8-bytes binary/integer values. The varying-length prefix, of course, will always be integer and will be 2 bytes.

Comment: @user2338816 Thanks. What is the maximum value of an unsigned two-byte COMP-4 field? I'm assuming it is the figure I've used, and if DB2 on i using COMP-4 for VARCHAR, I'm hoping it is correct :-) There's always the manuals, I suppose...

Comment: Two issues get involved. First, the `*NOSTDTRUNC` compile option can ensure that truncation happens at half-, full- or double-word boundaries. This helps overcome the issue of four decimal digits in `9(4)`. But `S9(4)` requires extra handling because 'unsigned' isn't supported. The 2-byte value must be manipulated into the low-order bytes of a 4-byte binary field in order to eliminate potential negative values. Make sense?

Comment: @user2338816 Thanks again. Very useful. I've never heard of a forced signed field for a binary, so learn something new every day.

Comment: COBOL in the midrange line doesn't have the usage base to compete with the RPG language series. It stays advanced in terms of ILE and general feature set; but various details slip by, probably because developers never ask. For COBOL developers, 2-byte binary usage is relatively rare and 4-byte rarely needs to use that bit. So it just seldom makes a difference.